# SQL query to display table in pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `ABC` (`ID`, `PaperNumber`), I want to display ID of people in pairs that have worked on same paper with the number of papers that they have worked on.

Like in pair of 2 `(a1,a2)(a1,a3)(a2,a3)` for a1, a2, a3 being ID for same paper number.

Comment: give a more clear example of table ABC and your required output properly.

Answer (score 3):

Do a self join, with `GROUP BY`:

```
select a1.id, a2.id, count(*)
from abc a1
  join abc a2 on  a1.PaperNumber = a2.PaperNumber
              and a1.id < a2.id
group by a1.id, a2.id
```

**Edit**: Missed the count part, now fixed.